# Using php variable in href html links

Tags: php, html, href

here is what i am trying to do

```
 $store='something.com';
 echo  '<div><h3>click on</h3><a href='.$store.'>host</a></p></div>';
```

what it output is

something.com

instead it should use something.com as link and output need to be host.

try for sometime to do it my own but havn't achieved any success.

Comment: Its a very basic question.Google it before asking such questions.

Comment: i know googled upto 5 pages before asking here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am agree with the Answer of **Ma'moon** and it is right.

Php code does not work inside the single quotes ' ', so its required to place code inside the double quotes " ".

You can also use following method instead ↓

```
$store='something.com';
echo  "<div><h3>click on</h3><a href='$store'>host</a></p></div>";
```

Answer (score 6):

This code will help you out:

```
<?php
$store='something.com';
echo  '<div><h3>click on</h3><a href="'.$store.'">host</a></p></div>';
```

Note the double quotes (") between the string concatenation (') this is needed by the browser to make render the proper href element.